# How to get location from map pin in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am using the MKMapView object and I am able to create pins and place them on the map. What I am trying to do now is get the information back from the pin. For example in my

```
- (MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

I create my pins and set them on the map. I am also creating buttons to use when a user clicks on the pin. All that works well and good. Now my question is when that button is clicked how do I get information from that clicked pin? Below is a small sample code of how I currently have it setup. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"location"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);

    UIButton* callout = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [callout addTarget:self action:@selector(loadDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = callout;
    return annView;
}

- (void)loadDetails:(id)sender
{
    //TODO: Get pin coordinates or address and match it back to an array of available address to show details in a new view
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the target of your callout, respond to the delegate method

```
mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:
```

The `annotationView` will have an `annotation` property with the coordinate.

Comment: This worked nicely for me. Only question I have is with this do I have to still create the button? I just feel like it's a waste if the button isn't actually being set or anything.

Comment: I think you have to use `[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]` to create a button, but you don't have to set a target/action. It is set up differently than the detail disclosure in a table view. Try it and comment back here if it works.

Comment: It does work by just creating the button and setting the callout to it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class that derives from MKPinAnnotationView that has a property of `id<MkAnnotationView>`.  During the method above, create this new object instead of the MKPinAnnotationView and set the `id<MKAnnotation>` property to the annotation passed in.

Comment: How would this help if the sender shows that it is a button instead of a MKPinAnnotationView?